# Is it legal to define a piecewise define a function like this?

Tags: functions, definition

I'm trying to piecewise define a function $h$ using two other functions $f$ and $g$. I want to use $h$ to draw conclusions on a certain set $T$ that's a union of two other sets $A$ & $B$.

$ h(n_z) = \begin{cases} f(n_z), & \mbox{if } f(n_z) \in A \wedge f(n_z) \notin B \wedge g(n_z) \notin A \\ g(n_z), & \mbox{if } g(n_z) \in B \wedge g(n_z) \notin A \wedge f(n_z) \notin B \\ f(n_z), & \mbox{if } f(n_z) \in A \wedge \exists n_y \in \mathbb N, g(n_y) \in B \end{cases} $

My question is, is it legal to do such a definition? Keep in mind that I've already defined $f$ & $g$ in the proof I'm doing and I'm not simply pulling them out of thin air.

Comment: Police will be banging on the door in 3, 2, 1... Seriously, sure it's legal, but what if $f(n_z) \notin A \land g(n_z) \notin B$?

Comment: Based on my definition, of f & g I don't think that such an occurence is possible. $ \exists f : \mathbb N \rightarrow X, \forall a \in A, \exists n_a \in \mathbb N, f(n_a) = a $.   
$ \exists g : \mathbb N \rightarrow B, \forall b \in B, \exists n_b \in \mathbb N, g(n_b) = b $.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me without context, but that's not necessary. The point is, you have to cover all possibilities, and if you do, you're fine.

Comment: Alright then. Thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

Such an definition is legal, or - how it's usually called - *well-defined*, if

- the cases do not overlap
- each possible condition is regarded by one of the cases

In other words, for each possible state, exactly one of the conditions must be fulfilled.

---

It is difficult to evalute this in this case, as we don't know the context. It seems, that the case $f(n_z)\notin A, g(n_z)\notin B$ is not considered, but maybe this case does not occur?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tomas. Like I ventured to explain to Daniel Fischer, based on how I defined $f$ and $g$ such a set of circumstances would never occur. $f(n_z)$ and $g(n_z)$ either have to be in $A$, $B$ or both. Them not being in either is out of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I read your discussion only after answering. Anyway, one other critical point would be $f(n_z)\in A\cap B$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb N: g(n)\notin B$. Can this happen?

Comment: Hmm ... I don't think I had taken that into consideration. I think I'm going to have to add more cases.